# How do you import a local jQuery into webview for VS Code extensions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, webview, vscode-extensions

how does one import jquery into webview? I attempted to modify:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/webview-sample/

to utilize the jquery library by adding it to the same location as main.js and then adding something like this:

```
const jqueryPathOnDisk = vscode.Uri.joinPath(this._extensionUri, 'media', 'jquery-3.6.0.min.js');
const jqueryUri = (jqueryPathOnDisk).with({ 'scheme': 'vscode-resource' });
```

followed by

```
<script nonce="${nonce}" src="${jqueryUri}"></script>
```

Around here in the code:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/116b0aa1ade25bfd3c6f3df0847200089b82b72f/webview-sample/src/extension.ts#L171

But unfortunately this doesn’t seem to work.

I've also attempted to delete the following line:

```
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none'; style-src ${webview.cspSource}; img-src ${webview.cspSource} https:; script-src 'nonce-${nonce}';">
```

from this file:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/webview-sample/src/extension.ts

And then importing a cdn but that also does not work. No matter what window.jQuery returns undefined.

Any insight would. be appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any errors when opening VSCode devtools? (Help>Toggle Dev tools)

Comment: Not that I could see relating specifically to jQuery. When I inspect the dom, I see main.js there but not jquery.js